# Error in knn: NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 6) and warinings about NAs being introduced by coercion

Tags: r, knn

I've been asked to apply `knn` to data for "income", based on "age", "gender" and "occupation" from the adults.txt data. This is my code after loading the data into R.

```
library(class)
set.seed(1234)
ind <- sample(2, nrow(adult), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.75, 0.25))
adult.training <- adult[ind==1, c(1,7,10)]
adult.test <- adult[ind==2, c(1,7,10)]
adult.trainLabels <- adult[ind==1, c(15)]
adult.testLabels <- adult[ind==2, c(15)]
adult_pred <- knn(train=adult.training, test=adult.test, cl=adult.trainLabels, k=3)
```

I get the following errors:

```
Error in knn(train=adult.training, test=adult.test, cl=adult.trainLabels, :
NA/NAN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 6)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In knn(train=adult.training, test=adult.test, cl=adult.trainLabels, :
NAs introduced by coercion
2: In knn(train=adult.training, test=adult.test, cl=adult.trainLabels, :
NAs introduced by coercion`
```

Is it possible to generate `knn` data for "income" based on the above variables two of which are factors?

Comment: Where is the `adults.txt` data? Please make sure your example is [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: The data can be downloaded from this link https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data

Comment: Your question should be complete without having to download external data. Suggestions for how to do this were provided in the link i gave on how to make your problem reproducible. So you want to run `knn` with categorical data? That doesn't make much sense. `knn` works with "Euclidean distances". What's the distance between a "male" and "female"? You might want to look for a different statistical technique.

Comment: @MrFlick thanks for that. I do know that knn will not run on variables that are factors, maybe the task that I was given was a bit vague. I'll try an alternative approach.

Comment: As much as this is years later I would like to shed some light on the topic- KNN can be ran using categorical variable outcomes. If your variable is male & female then separate levels into binary variables but as a target variable it is more then acceptable. Male or Female would be a classification the Euclidean distance is the distance between variables. 1 - 0 from binary would result in an Male or Female outcome.